# Adding loop cuts without unwanted details

Tags: modeling, mesh, topology

I just get into blender modelling and have a mesh/topology question/problem which I accounter currently quite often and want to ask you how to resolve it. In the first image you see my current mesh with a subdiv:
[image: current mesh with subdiv]
Here without the subdiv to better reveal the mesh:

[image: current mesh without subdiv]
To get a sharper edge, I usually would introduce a loop cut like shown in this image:

[image: wanted mesh with loop cut]
However as by nature of the loop cut I also add more polygons/cuts in the mesh where I do not need them, or also do not want them (shown as red crosses in the image). This extra lines give me often sharp edges, where I do not want to have them. Is there a way in this situtaion to get a clean edge in my mesh, where I want to it to be (green arrow) to get a sharp edge in my model, without using creases? How can I fix this? Is there a way to avoid this situation at all?

Thanks a lot!